# Gerador de tabelas html com PHP

Tags: php, html, tabela-html

o objetivo dessa tabela é simples, quando coloco as informações na textarea a mesma deve aparecer e quando não preencho as celulas dessa tabela tambem não devem aparecer, bom até ai esta tudo ocorrendo certo, porém essa tabela tem q ser zebrada e quando eu deixo de colocar uma das informações as cores se repetem e não ficam zebradas (isso ocorre porque nem sempre vou colocar todas as informações da text area), como nas imagens abaixo [image: Com todas as informações preenchidas]

[image: com algumas das informações preenchidas]

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST)){
$t1a = $_POST['txt1a'];
$t1b = str_replace("\r\n",'<br />',$_POST['txt1b']);
$t2a = $_POST['txt2a'];
$t2b = str_replace("\r\n",'<br />',$_POST['txt2b']);
$t3a = $_POST['txt3a'];
$t3b = str_replace("\r\n",'<br />',$_POST['txt3b']);
$t4a = $_POST['txt4a'];
$t4b = str_replace("\r\n",'<br />',$_POST['txt4b']);
$t5a = $_POST['txt5a'];
$t5b = str_replace("\r\n",'<br />',$_POST['txt5b']);
$t6a = $_POST['txt6a'];
$t6b = str_replace("\r\n",'<br />',$_POST['txt6b']);
$t7a = $_POST['txt7a'];
$t7b = str_replace("\r\n",'<br />',$_POST['txt7b']);
$t8a = $_POST['txt8a'];
$t8b = str_replace("\r\n",'<br />',$_POST['txt8b']);
$t9a = $_POST['txt9a'];
$t9b = str_replace("\r\n",'<br />',$_POST['txt9b']);
$t10a = $_POST['txt10a'];
$t10b = str_replace("\r\n",'<br />',$_POST['txt10b']);
$t11a = $_POST['txt11a'];
$t11b = str_replace("\r\n",'<br />',$_POST['txt11b']);
$t12a = $_POST['txt12a'];
$t12b = str_replace("\r\n",'<br />',$_POST['txt12b']);
$t13a = $_POST['txt13a'];
$t13b = str_replace("\r\n",'<br />',$_POST['txt13b']);
$t14a = $_POST['txt14a'];
$t14b = str_replace("\r\n",'<br />',$_POST['txt14b']);
$t15a = $_POST['txt15a'];
$t15b = str_replace("\r\n",'<br />',$_POST['txt15b']);

if(empty($t1a)){
    echo '<script>alert(" \n\Oops,\nO título do artigo é essencial!\n\nPreencha-o e tente novamente. ");</script>';
    exit;
}

$tab = '<!-- Título -->\n'; 
$tab .= '<div style=\"font-size:16pt; font-weight:bold; padding:10px; font-family: Roboto;\">'.$t1a.'</div>\n';

if(!empty($t1a) && !empty($t1b)){ 
    $tab .= '<!-- Descrição -->\n';
    $tab .= '<div style=\"font-size:12pt; padding:10px; font-family: Roboto;\">'.$t1b.'</div>\n\n';
}
$tab .= '<table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" style=\"font-family:Roboto, sans-serif;\">\n';
$tab .= '<tbody>\n\n';                  

if(!empty($t2a) && !empty($t2b)) {
    $tab .= '<!-- Linha 1 -->\n';
    $tab .= '<tr style=\"background-color:#D9E2F3;\">\n';
    $tab .= '<td width=\"20%\" style=\"border:1px solid #AAAAAA; padding:5px; font-size:10pt; font-weight:800;\">'.$t2a.'</td>\n';
    $tab .= '<td width=\"80%\" style=\"border:1px solid #AAAAAA; border-left:none; padding:5px; font-size:10pt;\">'.$t2b.'</td>\n';
    $tab .= '</tr>\n\n';
}

if(!empty($t3a) && !empty($t3b)){
    $tab .= '<!-- Linha 2 -->\n';
    $tab .= '<tr style=\"background-color:#EEEEEE;\">\n';
    $tab .= '<td width=\"20%\" style=\"border:1px solid #AAAAAA; border-top:none; padding:5px; padding-top:5px; font-size:10pt; font-weight:800;\">'.$t3a.'</td>\n';
    $tab .= '<td width=\"80%\" style=\"border:1px solid #AAAAAA; border-left:none; border-top:none; padding:5px; padding-top:5px; font-size:10pt;\">'.$t3b.'</td>\n';
    $tab .= '</tr>\n\n';
}

if(!empty($t4a) && !empty($t4b)){
    $tab .= '<!-- Linha 3 -->\n';
    $tab .= '<tr style=\"background-color:#D9E2F3;\">\n';
    $tab .= '<td width=\"20%\" style=\"border:1px solid #AAAAAA; border-top:none; padding:5px; padding-top:5px; font-size:10pt; font-weight:800;\">'.$t4a.'</td>\n';
    $tab .= '<td width=\"80%\" style=\"border:1px solid #AAAAAA; border-left:none; border-top:none; padding:5px; padding-top:5px; font-size:10pt;\">'.$t4b.'</td>\n';
    $tab .= '</tr>\n\n';
}

if(!empty($t5a) && !empty($t5b)){ 
    $tab .= '<!-- Linha 4 -->\n';
    $tab .= '<tr style=\"background-color:#EEEEEE;\">\n';
    $tab .= '<td width=\"20%\" style=\"border:1px solid #AAAAAA; border-top:none; padding:5px; padding-top:5px; font-size:10pt; font-weight:800;\">'.$t5a.'</td>\n';
    $tab .= '<td width=\"80%\" style=\"border:1px solid #AAAAAA; border-left:none; border-top:none; padding:5px; padding-top:5px; font-size:10pt;\">'.$t5b.'</td>\n';
    $tab .= '</tr>\n\n';
}

if(!empty($t6a) && !empty($t6b)){ 
    $tab .= '<!-- Linha 5 -->\n';
    $tab .= '<tr style=\"background-color:#D9E2F3;\">\n';
    $tab .= '<td width=\"20%\" style=\"border:1px solid #AAAAAA; border-top:none; padding:5px; padding-top:5px; font-size:10pt; font-weight:800;\">'.$t6a.'</td>\n';
    $tab .= '<td width=\"80%\" style=\"border:1px solid #AAAAAA; border-left:none; border-top:none; padding:5px; padding-top:5px; font-size:10pt;\">'.$t6b.'</td>\n';
    $tab .= '</tr>\n\n';
}

if(!empty($t7a) && !empty($t7b)){ 
    $tab .= '<!-- Linha 6 -->\n';
    $tab .= '<tr style=\"background-color:#EEEEEE;\">\n';
    $tab .= '<td width=\"20%\" style=\"border:1px solid #AAAAAA; border-top:none; padding:5px; padding-top:5px; font-size:10pt; font-weight:800;\">'.$t7a.'</td>\n';
    $tab .= '<td width=\"80%\" style=\"border:1px solid #AAAAAA; border-left:none; border-top:none; padding:5px; padding-top:5px; font-size:10pt;\">'.$t7b.'</td>\n';
    $tab .= '</tr>\n\n';
}

if(!empty($t8a) && !empty($t8b)){ 
    $tab .= '<!-- Linha 7 -->\n';
    $tab .= '<tr style=\"background-color:#D9E2F3;\">\n';
    $tab .= '<td width=\"20%\" style=\"border:1px solid #AAAAAA; border-top:none; padding:5px; padding-top:5px; font-size:10pt; font-weight:800;\">'.$t8a.'</td>\n';
    $tab .= '<td width=\"80%\" style=\"border:1px solid #AAAAAA; border-left:none; border-top:none; padding:5px; padding-top:5px; font-size:10pt;\">'.$t8b.'</td>\n';
    $tab .= '</tr>\n\n';
}

if(!empty($t9a) && !empty($t9b)){ 
    $tab .= '<!-- Linha 8 -->\n';
    $tab .= '<tr style=\"background-color:#EEEEEE;\">\n';
    $tab .= '<td width=\"20%\" style=\"border:1px solid #AAAAAA; border-top:none; padding:5px; padding-top:5px; font-size:10pt; font-weight:800;\">'.$t9a.'</td>\n';
    $tab .= '<td width=\"80%\" style=\"border:1px solid #AAAAAA; border-left:none; border-top:none; padding:5px; padding-top:5px; font-size:10pt;\">'.$t9b.'</td>\n';
    $tab .= '</tr>\n\n';
}

if(!empty($t10a) && !empty($t10b)){ 
    $tab .= '<!-- Linha 9 -->\n';
    $tab .= '<tr style=\"background-color:#D9E2F3;\">\n';
    $tab .= '<td width=\"20%\" style=\"border:1px solid #AAAAAA; border-top:none; padding:5px; padding-top:5px; font-size:10pt; font-weight:800;\">'.$t10a.'</td>\n';
    $tab .= '<td width=\"80%\" style=\"border:1px solid #AAAAAA; border-left:none; border-top:none; padding:5px; padding-top:5px; font-size:10pt;\">'.$t10b.'</td>\n';
    $tab .= '</tr>\n\n';
}

if(!empty($t11a) && !empty($t11b)){ 
    $tab .= '<!-- Linha 10 -->\n';
    $tab .= '<tr style=\"background-color:#EEEEEE;\">\n';
    $tab .= '<td width=\"20%\" style=\"border:1px solid #AAAAAA; border-top:none; padding:5px; padding-top:5px; font-size:10pt; font-weight:800;\">'.$t11a.'</td>\n';
    $tab .= '<td width=\"80%\" style=\"border:1px solid #AAAAAA; border-left:none; border-top:none; padding:5px; padding-top:5px; font-size:10pt;\">'.$t11b.'</td>\n';
    $tab .= '</tr>\n\n';
}

if(!empty($t12a) && !empty($t12b)){ 
    $tab .= '<!-- Linha 11 -->\n';
    $tab .= '<tr style=\"background-color:#D9E2F3;\">\n';
    $tab .= '<td width=\"20%\" style=\"border:1px solid #AAAAAA; border-top:none; padding:5px; padding-top:5px; font-size:10pt; font-weight:800;\">'.$t12a.'</td>\n';
    $tab .= '<td width=\"80%\" style=\"border:1px solid #AAAAAA; border-left:none; border-top:none; padding:5px; padding-top:5px; font-size:10pt;\">'.$t12b.'</td>\n';
    $tab .= '</tr>\n\n';
}

if(!empty($t13a) && !empty($t13b)){ 
    $tab .= '<!-- Linha 12 -->\n';
    $tab .= '<tr style=\"background-color:#EEEEEE;\">\n';
    $tab .= '<td width=\"20%\" style=\"border:1px solid #AAAAAA; border-top:none; padding:5px; padding-top:5px; font-size:10pt; font-weight:800;\">'.$t13a.'</td>\n';
    $tab .= '<td width=\"80%\" style=\"border:1px solid #AAAAAA; border-left:none; border-top:none; padding:5px; padding-top:5px; font-size:10pt;\">'.$t13b.'</td>\n';
    $tab .= '</tr>\n\n';
}

if(!empty($t14a) && !empty($t14b)){ 
    $tab .= '<!-- Linha 13 -->\n';
    $tab .= '<tr style=\"background-color:#D9E2F3;\">\n';
    $tab .= '<td width=\"20%\" style=\"border:1px solid #AAAAAA; border-top:none; padding:5px; padding-top:5px; font-size:10pt; font-weight:800;\">'.$t14a.'</td>\n';
    $tab .= '<td width=\"80%\" style=\"border:1px solid #AAAAAA; border-left:none; border-top:none; padding:5px; padding-top:5px; font-size:10pt;\">'.$t14b.'</td>\n';
    $tab .= '</tr>\n\n';
}       

$tab .= '</tbody>\n';
$tab .= '</table>\n';

echo '<script>
      $(function(){
          $("#preto").show();
          $("#modalHtml").modal("show");
          $("#gerado").val("'.$tab.'");
      });
      </script>';
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema não está no `PHP`, mas sim no seu html/css. Para criar uma tabela "zebrada" vc deve usar o seguinte CSS:

```css
tr {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #D9E2F3;
}
```

ps: Há muitos outros problemas no código apresentado, como a falta de separação entre código PHP e HTML/CSS, bem como falhas no HTML (como a falta de uso de classes no css).

O exemplo abaixo mostra como pelo menos resolver o problema da tabela zebrada.

```css
tr {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #D9E2F3;
}
```

```html
<p>tabela 1</p>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="font-family:Roboto, sans-serif;">
<tbody>

<tr>
  <td width="20%" style="border:1px solid #AAAAAA; padding:5px; font-size:10pt; font-weight:800;">texto 1</td>
  <td width="80%" style="border:1px solid #AAAAAA; border-left:none; padding:5px; font-size:10pt;">texto 2</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td width="20%" style="border:1px solid #AAAAAA; border-top:none; padding:5px; padding-top:5px; font-size:10pt; font-weight:800;">texto 3</td>
  <td width="80%" style="border:1px solid #AAAAAA; border-left:none; border-top:none; padding:5px; padding-top:5px; font-size:10pt;">texto 4</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td width="20%" style="border:1px solid #AAAAAA; border-top:none; padding:5px; padding-top:5px; font-size:10pt; font-weight:800;">texto 5</td>
  <td width="80%" style="border:1px solid #AAAAAA; border-left:none; border-top:none; padding:5px; padding-top:5px; font-size:10pt;">texto 6</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p>tabela 2</p>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="font-family:Roboto, sans-serif;">
<tbody>

<tr>
  <td width="20%" style="border:1px solid #AAAAAA; padding:5px; font-size:10pt; font-weight:800;">texto 1</td>
  <td width="80%" style="border:1px solid #AAAAAA; border-left:none; padding:5px; font-size:10pt;">texto 2</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td width="20%" style="border:1px solid #AAAAAA; border-top:none; padding:5px; padding-top:5px; font-size:10pt; font-weight:800;">texto 5</td>
  <td width="80%" style="border:1px solid #AAAAAA; border-left:none; border-top:none; padding:5px; padding-top:5px; font-size:10pt;">texto 6</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo me ajudou bastante mesmo, apesar de não ter sido eu que escrevi o código, eu achei q o problema fosse nas funções  do php e como sou iniciante tenho uma pouco de dificuldade, enfim sua ajuda me ajudou muito, obrigado

Comment: @WesleySilva neste caso, não esqueça de dar um "up vote" e marcar a resposta como aceita.